# How to generate a random number with 8 digits total in C#? (4 integer, 4 fractional part)

Tags: c#, .net, math, random

Something like these:

```
1234.5678
2345.6789
3456.7890
```

But not:

```
123.4567
```

Right now I do this:

```
double number = Math.Ceiling ( random.NextDouble ( ) * 10000000 ) * 0.001;
```

but that doesn't always give me 8 digits.

Any clever tricks to do this?

Comment: Given that the vast majority of decimal fractions have no exact representation when stored as double, you really should be using the Decimal type for this.

Comment: It is important that it has uniform distribution?

Comment: @spender: How do you mean? I just use them as seeders for other random functions. Is this not efficient?

Comment: @Servy, As uniform as Random provides is enough for me.

Comment: @JoanVenge I ask because if you're adding multiple calls of random together, rather than just manipulating one call, it will be even less uniform.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know this. Will use a single call then.

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve is one that is based on on decimal representation of numbers. The double datatype does not store its value as a decimal. It's stored as a binary mantissa and exponent. The set of numbers that can be represented perfectly using this representation is a different set to those that can stored perfectly using decimal representations.

Comment: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system#Fractions_in_binary  - 1/10 does not have a finite binary representation, and this causes 10 × 0.1 not to be precisely equal to 1 in floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Why is 3456.789 acceptable but 0123.4567 is not?

Comment: I see what you mean, I just need 4 digits for the integer part, but 0.123 is the same as 0.1230 so it's ok to have missing ones there, while still getting 4 digits for the majority.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `random.Next(10000000, 99999999+1) / 10000.0d;`

EDIT: added more 9s

EDIT2: fixed the 1 minus issue

EDIT3: added more 0s, how did my answer get upvoted so much?

Comment: `var n = random.Next(min, max)` generates a number n with min <= n < max, so using 9999999 instead of 9999999+1 isn't what you actually want (though you're unlikely to practically care in this case).

Comment: For readability, I'd recommend something like `10 * 1000 * 1000` and `100 * 1000 * 1000` instead of repeating 0's and 9's ad nauseum.

Comment: @JoanVenge the 1 minus issue is the fact that the upper limit of the range you specify is exclusive.  In other words, `Random.Next(10, 99)` returns an integer between 10 and 98.  The correct call to get a random 2-digit integer would be `Random.Next(10, 100)`.

Comment: Also, that should be `10000d`, not 1000.

Comment: This seems to generate more digits than 4 for the integer part. Can you please check?

Answer (score 3):

Use one of these:

```
double number = Math.Ceiling(random.NextDouble() * 9000 * 10000 + 1000 * 10000) * 0.0001;
double number = Math.Ceiling(random.NextDouble() * 90000000 + 10000000) * 0.0001;
double number = random.Next(10000 * 10000 / 10, 10000 * 10000) / 10000d;
double number = random.Next(10000000, 100000000) / 10000d;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
Random r = new Random();
var item = r.Next(10000000, 100000000) * 0.0001m;
```

Per spender's comment below... explanation as to why you I use decimal here:

1. Jon Skeet publicly shamed many of us for choosing double at one of his talks at Codemash in Ohio.
2. Doubles are used by hipsters, and
3. Decimal will prevent precision issues that are introduced by the use of double.  Keep in mind that when you need lots of digits after the dot, you should use double.  If you need less, but need them to maintain accuracy, use decimal.

Comment: probably worth explaining why you chose decimal for this calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Generate 8 single random digits and then concatenate them together.

Comment: Requires a parsing step. Slow.

Comment: @Servy as long as the first digit is between 1 and 9, you should get the same distribution.  Assembling digits gives you `9 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 == 9E8` possible results, and picking a number between 1E8 and 1E9 - 1 gives you `1E9 - 1E8 == 9E8` possible results.

Answer (score 1):

```
double number = random.Next(1000 * 1000, 1000 * 1000 * 10) / 1000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double rndNumber = new Random().NextDouble(); 
string testNumber = (rndNumber * 99999999).ToString("0000.0000");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int num1 = rnd.Next(1000,9999);
int num2 = rnd.Next(1000,9999);
Console.WriteLine(num1.ToString()+"."+num2.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double number = Double.Parse(r.Next(10000000, 99999999).ToString().Insert(4,"."));
```